# Strange JPA compilation errors

Tags: java, maven, jpa

I get the following compile errors when trying to use JPA 2.1 and EclipseLink 2.6

```
em.getCriteriaBuilder()
```

> java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   method getCriteriaBuilder()
>     location: variable em of type javax.persistence.EntityManager

```
Expression<Boolean>
```

> java: type javax.persistence.criteria.Expression does not take parameters

```
TypedQuery<Foo> query = em.createQuery(queryString, Foo.class);
```

> java: method createQuery in interface javax.persistence.EntityManager cannot be applied to given types;
>     required: java.lang.String
>     found: java.lang.String,java.lang.Class
>     reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

My pom.xml contains the following dependencies for JPA

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I can only think that the compiler is using a different JPA version where such methods I am trying to use above did not exist. However the pom clearly contains the 2.1 implementation.

These compilation errors are happening while I am attempting to convert a non maven project to an Intellij IDEA maven project (so everything worked before).

Full pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<groupId>REDACTED</groupId>
<artifactId>REDACTED</artifactId>

<properties>
    <appengine.app.version>1</appengine.app.version>
    <appengine.target.version>1.7.5</appengine.target.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <!-- if your container implements Servlet API older than 3.0, use "jersey-container-servlet-core"  -->
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-mvc</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                <webResources>
                    <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Edit: result of running mvn dependency:tree

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ REDACTED ---
[INFO] REDACTED:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided (scope not updated to 
compile)
[INFO] +- jstl:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.persistence:commonj.sdo:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish:javax.json:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.6:compile
[INFO] +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:provided (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:jar:2.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.17:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.4.0-b10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.17:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.17:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.4.0-b10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.4.0-b10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.4.0-b10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.4.0-b10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.17:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.17:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:jar:2.17:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-mvc:jar:2.17:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.appengine:appengine-testing:jar:1.7.5:test
[INFO] \- com.google.appengine:appengine-api-stubs:jar:1.7.5:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You could run `mvn dependency:tree` which should tell you if incorrect dependencies are getting in

Comment: @Raghuram I ran the command and posted the results. Nothing seems to be conflicting.

Comment: I just tested your `pom.xml` (in Eclipse) and everything works fine. Have you tried updating the Maven project from IntelliJ IDEA ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the Google App Engine and Maven Facets of Intellij IDEA are incompatible. I chose to create the project from the skeleton-archetype of com.google.appengine.archetypes and ignored the GAE IDE integration feature. This solved the compliation errors.